# How do I get my 'Edit' button turn into 'Done' while editing?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I've read a few posts, but do not see how to implement it in my own code. I've got a bar button item (Edit) which I dragged from the object library; it does the job, but I would like it to display 'Done' whilst in editing mode - any help will be much appreciated. My code looks like this:

```
@IBAction func editButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.editing = !self.editing {

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        // Delete the row from the data source
        lessons.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        saveLessons()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {

        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}


// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let itemToMove = lessons[fromIndexPath.row]

    lessons.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)

    lessons.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)

    saveLessons()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `setEditing`

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
   super.setEditing(editing, animated:animated)
   if editing == true {
     // set title of the bar button to 'Done'
     editBarButton.title = "Done"      
   } else {
     // set title of the bar button to 'Edit'
     editBarButton.title = "Edit"
   }
}
```

or shorter using the Ternary Conditional Operator

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
   super.setEditing(editing, animated:animated)
   editBarButton.title = editing ? "Done" : "Edit"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vadian - how do you set the title?

Comment: You need a reference to the button. It depends on your design. You could assign the predefined `rightBarButtonItem` or `leftBarButtonItem` in Interface Builder to the button or create a custom `IBOutlet`

Comment: I created a custom IBOutlet (IBOutlet weak var editBarButton), but do not know how to write it in the method... I'd like first title to be 'Done' and the second one to be 'Edit'.

Comment: It's very simple. `UIBarButtonItem` has a `title` property. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Vadian - I tried both, but my edit button won't change into 'Done' when tapped... Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you set the button to `System Item` > `Edit`?

Comment: Yes I have - do I need to set it to Custom?

Comment: I guess you have to remove `self.editing = !self.editing` because the `Edit` button toggles the state automatically.

Comment: I have not tried that yet, but your previous comment helped a hell of a lot! I changed System Item to 'Custom' and its title to 'Edit'. At runtime, my button shows 'Edit' and then 'Done' when tapped :)!!  Thanks for your help, Vadian.